# Scilab multiple lines text uicontrol

Tags: scilab, uicontrol

I'm trying to show a text with multiple lines, but I can't get the syntax for that in Scilab. I've already try using "|" and "\n".

Could anyone change this code bellow to support multiple lines on the String *"Informacoes sobre o programa e como usa-lo"*?

`handles.textoTutorial=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.5014641,0.0514019,0.3989751,0.8987539],'Relief','default','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Informacoes sobre o programa e como usa-lo','Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','textoTutorial','Callback','')`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple lines or a vector of string to a `text` uicontrol: this will give the error (Scilab 5.5.1) : `Wrong dimension of property 'String' : expecting a string.`

But I will give you 2 ugly answers:

First: Use a `edit` style uicontrol, and set the `max` and `min` properties such that `max-min > 1`. Then the uicontrol allow multiple line editing and so the string property can be set with `sprintf('a line\nan other line')`. The problem is it's still an editable uicontrol (the text can be modified). The only workaround i see is to switch the `enable` property to `off`, but this will give a grey color to the font, no matter the `foregroundcolor` property, and depending on the backgroundcolor, your text could be hard to see.

Second: You could have your text on multiple line if you constrain the uicontrol to fit your text (see `constraints` and `createConstraints` in the help); I don't know the difficulty of such a task, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (with a bonus :-):

```
clf
text = "<html><font color=""red"">Informacoes sobre o programa e como usa-lo</font><br>"+..
       "Line #2<br>" + ..
       "Line #3<br>" + ..
       "etc…";
uicontrol("style","text","string",text, 'Position',[0.501,0.05,0.4,0.9],'unit','normalized')
```

It yields

[image]